# webview onPageFinished does not detect the selection of a video from the home page on YouTube mobile version

Tags: java, android, youtube

I entered this code under onPageFinished:

`edittext1.setText(webview1.getUrl());`

When I google YouTube and i select YouTube, edittext changes its name, But when I select a video on the home page in YouTube page, edittext does not change the name

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this code? :

```java
binding.webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
      binding.urlEditText.setText(url); // set the url
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return false;
   }
});
```